# Reference a worksheet via a variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I want to reference Sheets within a Workbook via an index. - essentially as I want to run through a loop and clear certain cells on several worksheets.

At present I've written some vba which includes code like:

Sheet36.Activate 
Range("B3:T201").ClearContents

repeated each time for each sheet, for instance: 
Sheet37.Activate 
Range("B3:T201").ClearContents

All answers appreciated.

Comment: So, you want to loop through each sheet and then use an if statement or case select statement to determine what to clear on any given sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clarification added thanks to ExcelHero.**

You could use a Collection of the specific worksheets you are interested in. Something like:

```
Private mChosenSheets As Collection

Sub Init()
    Set mChosenSheets = New Collection
    
    ' Add here whichever worksheets you want in your iterable list
    mChosenSheets.Add Sheet6
    mChosenSheets.Add Sheet36
    mChosenSheets.Add Sheet38
    ' etc...
    
End Sub

Sub ClearChosenSheets()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    
    For Each sht In mChosenSheets
        sht.Range("B3:T201").ClearContents
    Next
    
End Sub
```

The `Workbook.Worksheets` collection can be used if you just want to iterate through every worksheet in the workbook.

Comment: Each worksheet in a workbook is already a member of two built-in collections: `Sheets` and `Worksheets`. What would be the purpose of overtly adding them to another collection with regards to this question?

Comment: I don't think the Op wants to iterate through the Worksheets collection of the Workbook object (ie every worksheet sheet). I think he wants to iterate through a list he's generated of specific worksheets (ie only some sheets). This answer was meant to show him a way of adding just those worksheets to his own iterable collection.

Comment: Thanks All. Second solution fits my need better (as i only want to clear certain sheets).

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a few sheets that you wish to clear a range on, it's easy to reference them all at the same time like so:

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet36", "Sheet37").Range("B3:T201").ClearContents
```

But if you really want to loop all of the sheets, then this is how:

```
Dim sh
For Each sh In Worksheets
    sh.Range("B3:T201").ClearContents
Next
```